# SAS Datasets Read From Multiple Z/OS Tapes. Number of Tape Volumes Limitation?

Tags: sas, zos

I need to read large SAS data sets stored on tape in Z/OS that are spread across multiple tapes.  I am not in a position to move this data off tape and to store it on our DASD storage on our mainframe.

I am wondering does SAS 9.4 on Z/OS have a limitation to the number of tapes it can utilize when accessing a dataset spread over multiple tapes?

Currently when accessing a SAS dataset that is spread over multiple tapes I declare a libref similar to this:

```
libname mf v9tape 'mainframe dataset name';
```

I have been able to successfully read dataset that are spread across multiple tapes this way problem free.

Reading more about the libref statement there is a `volser` option that I could use the declare which tapes are required, however as per the documentation utilizing this option limits me to utilizing no more than 30 tapes.  I am wondering if I do not use this option will SAS apply the 30 tape limit to this statement as it would if I utilized the `volser` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not SAS literate, but your question made me curious. z/OS documents that multivolume tape data sets can span over 255 volumes at max (see z/OS DFSMS Using Data Sets, "Maximum Data Set Size", "Maximum Number of Volumes"). So this 30 volume limit is a SAS limit.

Reading the SAS manual (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hosto390/61886/HTML/default/viewer.htm#mvs-stmt-libname.htm) I understand that the *volser* limit applies when writing a new library, and you want specific volumes to be used. Or, when you want to read a tape library, but the data set is *not catalogued*, and you therefore need to specify the list of volumes.

Using the *volcount* you can write to as many as 255 volumes. I conclude that you may read a *catalogued* tape data set which is spread over as many as 255 volumes.

HTH